# Creating a variable in PHP that can only be accessed by one function

Tags: php

I have a variable that is only used by 1 function. Right now, I'm declaring the variable as a global variable and using `global` inside the function to access the variable. However, I'm afraid I might override the variable elsewhere by accident. Is there a way to make a variable accessible by only 1 function without using a class?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
$i=0;
function increment(){
  global $i;
  $i++;
  echo $i;
}

for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
  increment();
// outputs 12345689
```

Comment: why not declare it inside the function? or pass it as an argument to the function?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't declare this variable within that function.  If you need data from the outside, add a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a local variable whose value persists from one call to the next, declare it `static`:

```
function increment() {
    static $i = 0;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you doing this:

```
function increment(){
  static $i = 0;
  $i++;
  echo $i;
}
```

Any operation performed on the static variable is done at its address. So you wont even loose your resulted value.